# Cannot close the active listbox window

Tags: python, class, tkinter, destroy

I've created a function `btnExit` outside the `class myWindow` and a method inside the class with the same name. I have called each of these in numerous ways and with a number of recommendations to close the current window. Nothing works.
It's obvious from my code that I just learning Python and come from c++.

Two problems:

1. if I use `command=self.btnExit`, I get this error: `object has no attribute 'btnExit'`.
2. I can call `command=btnExit` the function is accessed, but nine of the functions I try close the window.

   ```
   self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="EXIT", fg="red", command=btnExit)
   ```

Minimally functional code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Cura json iteration reporter

import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)        #disable root window
root.withdraw()

#test data
display = [
"   0   .  name = Extruder",
"   1   .  version = 2",
"   2   .  metadata",
"   3   .  .  type = extruder",
"   4   .  .  author = Ultimaker",
"   5   .  .  manufacturer = Unknown",
"   6   .  .  setting_version = 1",
"   7   .  .  visible = False",
"   8   .  .  position = 0",
"   9   .  settings",
"  10   .  .  machine_settings"
]
line_cnt = 10
pathFilenameExt = "D:/Python/$my Projects/CURA json profiles examples/fdmextruder.def.json"
fileDialogTitle = "Cura profile files"
win_size = '500x500'

    # !!!! - this btnExit outside of any class class
def btnExit():
    choice = messagebox.askquestion("Exit Program?", "Are you sure?", icon='warning')
    if choice == 'yes':
        #???what goes here to close current window????
        myWindow.destroy()

class myWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        display = []         #make sure display list is empty

    # !!!! - this btnExit is in the class whose window I want to close
    def btnExit(self):
        choice = messagebox.askquestion("Exit Program?", "Are you sure?", icon='warning')
        if choice == 'yes':
            #???what goes here to close current window????
            self.parent.deiconify()
            self.top.destroy()

    #now that we have a dictionary, create a readable formatted list and display it.
    # use current filename  NOTE: l1_text = StringVar() must be declared at top as global to be changed???
    def displysList(self):
        self.tk = Tk()        #creates a NEW window each time
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text = pathFilenameExt)
        self.label1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="New File", fg="blue", command=main)
        self.btn1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="EXIT", fg="red", command=btnExit)
        self.btn2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)

        self.title('CURA json Lister')
        self.resizable(width=True, height=True)
        self.geometry(win_size)
        #create scroll bar for listbox
        self.scrollbary = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')
        self.scrollbary.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y' )
        self.scrollbarx = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal')
        self.scrollbarx.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'x' )

        height =400     #in characters wider and taller than the screen to use all space available
        width = 400
        #list box create
        self.list2Box=tk.Listbox(self, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.list2Box.config(height=height, width=width)
        self.scrollbary.config(command = self.list2Box.yview )
        self.scrollbarx.config(command = self.list2Box.xview )

        i = 0
        while i < line_cnt:
            self.list2Box.insert(END,display[i])
            i += 1
        self.list2Box.pack(side='left')

def main():
    #no other setup needed here for now
    windA = myWindow            #CREATE AN INSTANCE TO CALL ppd
    windA.displysList(root)   #redisplay each new file
#end main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code that is unrelated to the question being asked. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: There are numerous problems with your code. For starters, to create an instance of `class myWindow` you need to ***call*** it and pass any arguments it expects. i.e. In `main()` it should be `windA = myWindow(root)`. Also note that generally you can't call `Tk()` more than once within a `tkinter`-based program. To create a new window use `tk.Toplevel()`. Here's a little [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) about it.